# How to load new content into a UITableView using IBAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, load, updates

FYI - Noob `iOS` developer here.

My current setup is a `UIViewController` with a UIView within, then a `UITableView` within the `UIVIew`. So it goes like this...

```
UIViewController --> UIView --> UITableView
```

The reason for this is because I have other elements wrapped with the tableview. The `UIViewController` loads dynamic content into the table view. I have a segmented Control in which I want to use to switch the content within the table view.

I've read something on `[table reload]` and `[table beginUpdate]` but don't understand how to use it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so `[table reloadData]` will reload the data (so if you change the data and want to update the table with the necessary data call this), but straight after you call that make sure to call `[table setNeedsDisplay]` to refresh the UI.`[table beginUpdates]`
begins a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the receiver. You end the processes with `[table endUpdates];`

Make sure you set your table view's `dataSource` and `delegate` to self, this can be done through the xib and programmatically like this:

```
[table setDelegate: self];
```

or

```
[table setDataSource: self];
```

As said:

Call this `delegate` method for `UISegmentedControl`

```
    - (void)segmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl*)segmentedControl didSelectIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex
{
   if(selectedIndex == 0)
   {
     // Update the data
   }
   else if(selectedIndex == 1)
   {
     // Update the data
   }

   [table reloadData];
   [table setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Midhun MP had a similar answer but you explained the difference. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a method for  `UIControlEventValueChanged` event of`UISegmentedControl` for this.

```
[yourSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And implement the `segmentChanged` method like:

```
- (void)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
   UISegmentedControl *mySegment = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

   switch ([mySegment selectedSegmentIndex])
   {
       case 1:
           //load first contents
       break;
       case 2:
          //load second contents   
       break;
       default:
       break;
   }
   [self.yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

Your `UIView` named `*myView` and your `UITableView` named `*myTableView`,
the time you want to reload `tableview`, in your `UIViewController` , you should reload `tableview` like this:

```
[self.myView.myTableView reload];
```

and make sure `tableview's` `delegate` and `dataSourceDelegate` is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set the delegate & data source for tableview in ViewController.h file like

UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate.

Implement delegate & datasource methods in ViewController.m file

```
[tableview SetDelagate:self];

[tableview SetDatasource:self];
```

Implement the delegate methods.

And reload the table using

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

method.